# Why does my version of filter perform so differently than Swifts?

Tags: swift, filter, instruments, higher-order-functions

As an exercise I've rewritten a few of Swift's higher order functions, one being `.filter`. I decided to measure my version of `.filter` against Swift's using instruments and I'm rather confused about the results.

Here's what my version of filter looks like, which I admit may be incorrect.

```
extension Array {
    func myFilter(predicate: Element -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        var filteredArray = [Element]()
        for x in self where predicate(x) {
            filteredArray.append(x)
        }

        return filteredArray
    }
}
```

### What Happened

**My Filter**

- Overall CPU consumption: 85.7%
- My Filter's consumption: 67.9%

[image]
[image]

**Swift's Filter**

- Overall CPU consumption: 57.7%
- My Filter's consumption: 70.9%

[image]
[image]

### What I expected

I expected similar performance. I'm confused why my filter function call itself would consume less CPU yet my overall application CPU is nearly 30% higher.

### My Question

If I've written `filter` wrong, please help me to understand my error(s). Otherwise please point out why Swift's `filter` reduces CPU load by 30% over mine.

Comment: My guess is that your method works on an array, which means it processes all the data in a loop, assigns a new array and returns it - your `for...in` loop then iterates through that array (effectively for a second time). `SequenceType<A>.filter()` works on a `SequenceType<T>`, which only guarantees that it can be looped over and thus opens up the implementation to be a generator (ie. lazily evaluated) - this results in the data only being enumerated once.

Comment: @RichardSzalay could you provide a better version of filter by chance? It would probably be worth of an accept and vote as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: One thing that might help is prefacing the closure argument with `@noescape` which allows the compiler to "make more aggressive optimizations" according to the documentation. Also, you can check [Apple's implementation of filter](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift) directly.

Comment: @MarcKhadpe thanks for this, I was going to hunt it down in the morning.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu I'd have to become familiar with Swift and get a Windows compiler first ;) The reason I commented is that I was making an assumption based on my experience with other languages/platforms.

Comment: @DanBeaulieu It appears that [these](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2014/10/13/swift-standard-library-generators-sequences-and-collections/) [two](https://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/generators-in-swift/) articles confirm my suspicions that Swift's Standard Library makes use of generators. The second article notes that due to the lack of a `yield` style operator, writing your own could be quite verbose (barring any closure based helpers that may or may not exist in the library).

Comment: Could you add your test code? Did you measure the concrete *time* needed for both filter methods? And (just to be sure!) did you compile your test code in Release mode? – I made a small test and filtered an array of 1,000,000,000 integers with `array.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }`, and your method was faster than the built-in filter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so after reading all posted comments, I decided to also benchmark, and here are my results. Oddly enough, the built-in `filter` seems to perform worse than a custom implementation.

**TL;DR;** Because your function is short, and the compiler has access to it source code, the compiler inlines the function call, which enables more optimisations.

Another consideration is as your `myFilter` declaration doesn't take into consideration exception throwing closures, thing that the built-in `filter` does.

Add `@inline(never)`, `throws` and `rethrows` to your `myFilter` declaration and you'll get similar results as for the built-in `filter`

### Research results

I used `mach_absolute_time()` to obtain accurate times. I didn't converted the results to seconds as I was merely interested in comparison. Tests were run on Yosemite 10.10.5 with Xcode 7.2.

```
import Darwin

extension Array {
    func myFilter(@noescape predicate: Element -> Bool) -> [Element] {
        var filteredArray = [Element]()
        for x in self where predicate(x) {
            filteredArray.append(x)
        }

        return filteredArray
    }
}

let arr = [Int](1...1000000)

var start = mach_absolute_time()
let _ = arr.filter{ $0 % 2 == 0}
var end = mach_absolute_time()
print("filter:         \(end-start)")

start = mach_absolute_time()
let _ = arr.myFilter{ $0 % 2 == 0}
end = mach_absolute_time()
print("myFilter:       \(end-start)")
```

In `debug` mode, `filter` is faster than `myFilter`:

```
filter:         370930078
myFilter:       479532958
```

In `release`, however, `myFilter` is much better than `filter`:

```
filter:         15966626
myFilter:       4013645
```

What's even more strange is that an exact copy of the built-in `filter` (taken from Marc's comment) behaves better than the built-in one.

```
extension Array {
    func originalFilter(
        @noescape includeElement: (Generator.Element) throws -> Bool
        ) rethrows -> [Generator.Element] {

            var result = ContiguousArray<Generator.Element>()

            var generator = generate()

            while let element = generator.next() {
                if try includeElement(element) {
                    result.append(element)
                }
            }

            return Array(result)
    }

}

start = mach_absolute_time()
let _ = arr.originalFilter{ $0 % 2 == 0}
end = mach_absolute_time()
print("originalFilter: \(end-start)")
```

With the above code, my benchmark app gives the following output:

```
filter:         13255199
myFilter:       3285821
originalFilter: 3309898
```

Back to `debug` mode, the 3 flavours of `filter` give this output:

```
filter:         343038057
myFilter:       429109866
originalFilter: 345482809
```

`filter` and `originalFilter` give very close results. Which makes me think that Xcode is linking against the debug version of Swifts stdlib. However when build in `release`, Swifts stdlib performs 3 times better than in `debug`, and this confused me.

So the next step was profiling. I hit `Cmd+I`, set the sample interval to 40us, and profiled the app two times: one when only the `filter` call was enabled, and one with `myFilter` enabled. I removed the printing code in order to have a stack-trace as clean as possible.

Built-in `filter` profiling:
[image: build in filter time profiling]
<sub>(source: [cristik-test.info](https://cristik-test.info/filter-built-in.png))</sub>

`myFilter`:
[image: myFilter time profiling]

Eureka!, I found the answer. There's no track of the `myFilter` call, meaning that the compiler inlined the function call, thus enabling extra optimizations that give a performance boost.

I added the `@inline(never)` attribute to `myFilter`, and it's performance degraded.

Next, to make it closer to the built-in filter was to add the `throws` and `rethrows` declaration, as the built-in filter allows passing closures that throw exceptions.

And surprise (or not), this is what I got:

```
filter: 11489238
myFilter: 6923719
myFilter not inlined: 9275967
my filter not inlined, with throws: 11956755
```

**Final conclusion:** the fact that the compiler can inline the function call, combined with lack of support for exceptions was responsible for the better performance of your custom filtering method.

The following code gives results very similar to the build-in `filter`:

```
extension Array {
    @inline(never)
    func myFilter(predicate: Element throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element] {
        var filteredArray = [Element]()
        for x in self where try predicate(x) {
            filteredArray.append(x)
        }

        return filteredArray
    }
}
```

### Original answer:

Swift's `filter` should perform better, because:

1. it has access to the internal state of the array and is not forced to go through the enumeration, which means at least one less function call
2. it might optimize the way it builds the result array

#1 might not give much difference, as function calls are not very expensive

#2 on the other hand might make a big difference for large arrays. Appending a new element to the array might result in the array needing to increase its capacity, which implies allocating new memory and copying the contents of the current state.

Comment: Looking at [the source for the default implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift), it appears that (1) Swift does use enumeration and (2) it does not do anything special to optimize how it builds the result array (i.e. it uses append() ). However, it does use a ContiguousArray rather than an Array to build the result, which is potentially more efficient for class and @objc types.

Comment: That is the default implementation for `SequenceType`, `Array` most likely overwrites it for efficiency reasons. I've yet to find yet, though, within the source code for Swift.

Comment: That might be the case, but I could not find any such implementation in the open source repository.

Comment: This is a beautiful answer, I'm going to open up a bounty on this tomorrow to get you some extra points. Thank you, there is so much to take in here.

Comment: Turning on Whole Optimization Mode made myFilter run 10% faster than Swifts which certainly backs your research.

Comment: Thanks again Cristik!

Comment: Thank you too for the bounty