# Why is not @noescape automatically applied to Swift closures when it is needed?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I wonder why the tag `noescape` isn't automatically detected and it needs to be explicitly applied.

In fact, it is somehow detected at compile time, because trying to add the @noescape tag to a func with escaping closures results in an error.

So the question is why... why `noescape` needs to be explicitly added and Apple did not create it to be automatically added when it is needed?

Comment: Who says it it not applied? Function inlining, for example, is by default applied if the compiler has access to the body of the function (see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540874/why-does-my-version-of-filter-perform-so-differently-than-swifts/34541727#34541727)), so it might that this happens for other possible optimizations also.

Comment: Well I could be making a wrong assumptions based on syntax, but attending to the fact that using a class property from the closure does requires using `self` unless it is explicitly tagged as @noescape. I would say it isn't automatically applied.

Comment: The compiler is build to take advantage of every possible optimization. And `@noescape` is intended more for libraries that come only with the headers, and the compiler doesn't know what happens inside the body of the functions. With access to the source code of the function, the compiler is able to tell if it can apply or not the optimizations that `@noescape` could bring (on the top of my head copy/release on the closure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Swift 3 makes a few changes here:

- [Non-escaping closures are the default.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0103-make-noescape-default.md) Now you don't have to apply `@noescape` to your function declarations that take closures as parameters if you want to require non-escaping closures. (Instead, you have to apply `@escaping` in cases where you *do* plan to store a closure past the return of your function.)
- The "escaping-ness" of a closure [is now part of the function type declaration](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0049-noescape-autoclosure-type-attrs.md). So instead of a parameter that looks like `@escaping completionHandler: (Bool, Error) -> Void`, it's `completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, Error) -> Void`.

It's kinda hard to rewrite my whole answer to reflect that, so I'll leave it here for now... read on for the *whys* behind escaping-ness, just remember to invert noescape/escaping declarations. :) Or read about [Escaping Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID546) in the Swift 3 version of *The Swift Programming Language*.

---

`@noescape` isn't just a hint for compiler optimizations; it's part of the interface that a function declaration presents to callers. Whether a parameter to a function is declared `@noescape` or allows escaping closures changes how a caller of that function writes the closure they pass as the parameter.

For example, given the function (from `SequenceType`):

```
func filter(@noescape includeElement: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Self.Generator.Element]
```

If I wanted to filter a collection based on some criteria that requires calling a method on `self`, I know I can safely do that without worrying about whether the closure will capture `self` and create a retain cycle.

```
// horribly contrived example
class Foo {
    var things: [Thing]
    func isCurrentlyAwesomeThing(thing: Thing) -> Bool { /*...*/ }
    func thingsThatAreAwesomeRightNow() -> [Thing] {
        return things.filter {
            return isCurrentlyAwesomeThing($0)
        }
    }
}
```

If `filter` permitted an escaping closure, the closure that calls `isCurrentlyAwesomeThing()` would capture `self`. (And thus require that method to be called with an explicit `self.` prefix.) And if the implementation of `filter` actually saved the closure beyond the runtime of that function, there'd be a memory leak because the closure retains `self` and `self` retains the array whose `filter` function received the closure.

When you call a function whose closure parameters aren't declared `@noescape`, you have to account for that possibility. This is why you see calls that add a `[weak self]` capture list and a strong redeclaration inside the closure to make sure `self` doesn't get deallocated during the closure. (Or at least an `[unowned self]` in cases where you're reasonably certain the closure won't persist longer than `self`.)

If closure parameters weren't able to be decorated as `@noescape` (or as non-escaping through the absence of that decorator), you wouldn't know when calling a function that takes a closure whether you have to be careful about what that closure captures.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any function parameter as a noescape you can't able store in another closure, you can't able use dispatch_asynch and you can't able to call non-noescape closure from the noescape closure

The scope of the noescape attribute it should be with in the that closure