# Is Array.filter cheaper than loop?

Tags: arrays, swift

There's a `filter` function in `Array`. I wonder it is cheaper than using usual `loop` like `for`.

If so, why?

Comment: Only a benchmark will answer this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to put it simply, it *is* a loop, it's really just syntactic sugar to make your code cleaner

```
let stuff = ["asdf", "asdf", ""]

var things: [String] = []

for item in stuff {
    if(!item.isEmpty) {
        things.append(item)
    }
}
```

is functionally identical to:

```
let stuff = ["asdf", "asdf", ""]
var things = stuff.filter{!$0.isEmpty}
```

6 lines down to 1.

It's possible that there may be some compiler optimizations that are done due to the type safety and predictability, though according to this: depending on your implementation your performance can vary:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34540874/why-does-my-version-of-filter-perform-so-differently-than-swifts/34541727#34541727)

Comment: you mean `for item in stuff {` and `if !item.isEmpty {`

Comment: whoops...that's what happens when you can't use refactor :)

Comment: it still wrong. you need to check if item not empty

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the link when I googled it. It is great.

Comment: Also isEmpty is a property not a method

Comment: I believe It's a computed property, and it is checking if it isn't empty, hence the !

Comment: Like @LeoDabus said, the code is wrong and it could be shorter as well: `for item in stuff where !item.isEmpty { things.append(item) }`.

Answer (score 10):

The cool thing now that Swift is open source is that we can verify this ourselves. [Here's the current source code for `Sequence.filter`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a147a582fec7f0bcf058d089d79fb0950c261db9/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L338-L356) (note that it already uses the new names `Sequence` and `Iterator`; `SequenceType` and `GeneratorType` will be renamed in Swift 3):

```
/// Returns an `Array` containing the elements of `self`,
/// in order, that satisfy the predicate `includeElement`.
@warn_unused_result
public func filter(
  @noescape includeElement: (Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool
) rethrows -> [Iterator.Element] {

  var result = ContiguousArray<Iterator.Element>()

  var iterator = self.makeIterator()

  while let element = iterator.next() {
    if try includeElement(element) {
      result.append(element)
    }
  }

  return Array(result)
}
```

It uses a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop, possibly because that code was written before `for ... in` was even a thing (I haven't verified that, though). But you can see that it is essentially a simple loop with no special optimizations.